Wrt VersionMadeBy and Interface call zipOpenNewFileInZip4_64
The external_fa is set as NULL and not 0 and the call to Zlib is intended to work fine across platforms Windows,UNIX, MAC etc.Could high byte be 0 here for VERSIONMADEBY field
I have tried with versionmade by as 45 and it seems to work on Windows. Yet to test across other platforms

Do you have a question? (Hint: questions end with a question mark.)
